# ¿como hago para leer numeros y poder evaluar una tecla especifica en cualquier momento de la ejecucion del programa?

Tags: dev-c++

El problema que tengo es que tengo que llenar una matriz y que durante el proceso de llenado si dijito la tecla 'd' me permita eliminar algun numero de los ingresados o si dijito 'l' pueda eliminarlos todos.
he probado con kbhit() y getch() pero al momento de introducir alguna letra no me deja que vuelva a ingresar numeros.
Adjunto un pequeño ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer.

```
int main(){
    int x;
    char tecla;
    do{
        if (kbhit()) {
           tecla = getch();
        } else {
           tecla = ' ';
        }
       if(tecla!=' '){
           if(tecla=='l'){
               cout<<"ele"<<endl;
           }else if(tecla=='v'){
               cout<<"uve"<<endl;
           }else if(tecla=='d'){
               cout<<"de"<<endl;
           }else{
               cin>>x;
               cout<<x<<endl;
           }
       }
   }while(true);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: si no agregas el codigo que tienes hasta ahora, no va a ser posible ayudarte

Comment: entiendo pero es que tengo 600 lineas de codigo(es un bingo) y pues no se si subirlo todo.

Comment: no.. todo no.. un ejemplo [minimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de tu problema.. si no, nadie va a poder decirte porque no te deja volver a ingresar numeros...

Comment: ya agregué algo pero no sé si se visualice bien.

Comment: me parece que esto anda bien.. o te da el error tambien?

Comment: si, el problema es que cuando ingreso alguna tecla no vuelve a permitir un numero.